# Characters cannot use in property name for metadata

Tags: search, managed-metadata, crawled-property

I want to add **custom property** in **advanced search** in SharePoint 2010. I want to know which characters are not allowed in **property name** for metadata?

Comment: While adding the name SharePoint checks for approved characters. So you can try entering the name and see if it allows.

Comment: Are you talking about Search Managed Properties or Managed Metadata properties?